# About solr document not to be commited based on condition

Tags: solr

I am trying to find a way to block the solr commit using solr api based on certain condition.

Currently, every solr document index has an unique id. So how could I update the solr api that it does not commit to  solr index if already the id is present based on my below code:

```
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

                solrDoc.addField("id", indexUrl);
solrDoc.addField("price",100);

HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(endpoint);
UpdateResponse response = server.add(solrDoc);

                server.commit();
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this related to git?

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking Solr for an SQL server... Solr commit is nothing like SQL commit.

The idea behind Solr commit is to lower the amount of writes to the disk. Solr is not transactional... you don't have a rollback ability - except maybe erasing the tlog folder manually. You'll need to rewrite the commit feature entirely to do what you want.

You can query Solr for the id's before sending them, but you have no ACID guarantees that by the time they are sent and committed there won't be other documents with the same id already in.

You could maybe get an ACID guarantee by using a shared SQL server to generate an ID for you. Or by using zooKeeper to do the same (although harder to configure).

Comment: Thanks for the input.Could you please provide a sample sinnpet as how could i retrieve the query only for id and then if not present then do an server commit

Comment: @user3732294 Any regular query (i.e. `id:URL`) would work as the response from Solr includes the count of documents that match. Also - it might be more effective to just add the document again instead - as long as the id field is defined as the uniqueKey for the collection, the old document will just be overwritten.